# SQL Server 2008 R2: Working with XML stored as BLOB (image data type)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, reporting-services, blob

A database on the `MS SQL Server 2008 R2` has a column which is stored as a BLOB (has a "image" data type) . I also know that the BLOB contains XML.

Is there any way for reporting services to extract this information?
How would I query or use the data that is stored within the XML BLOB?

I have read something along the line of casting the SQL IMAGE data type to the XML data type; then use `@xml.query` to get element/attribute values, would this be a good idea? How would I cast the BLOB (image data type) into XML data type?
How do I check if my XML have a schema or not (hence typed or untyped XML)?

Or are there easier ways of retrieving data within the BLOB that contains XML to use it to generate a `SSRS web report`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can cast the `Image` to `Xml` and then use features such as XQuery to parse the Xml document. You will however first need to cast it through `VARBINARY` as well.

```
SELECT CAST(cast(SomeXmlStoredAsBlob AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML) AS MyXml
FROM MyTable
```

I would recommend changing the column type ASAP - if all data is Xml, then convert it to Xml as per above, and if there are different formats, then use `VARBINARY(MAX)`

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a56f/2)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use SQL Server to extract data from your XML blob into a table.

You need to read in your blob value, then convert it into a variable of type `xml`, and from there, you can use some complicated syntax to query it.

Here's a little example:

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(2000)

SET @str = ''
SET @str = @str + '<users>'
SET @str = @str + '  <user>'
SET @str = @str + '     <firstName>Mike</firstName>'
SET @str = @str + '     <lastName>Gledhill</lastName>'
SET @str = @str + '     <age>31</age>'
SET @str = @str + '  </user>'
SET @str = @str + '  <user>'
SET @str = @str + '     <firstName>Mark</firstName>'
SET @str = @str + '     <lastName>Stevens</lastName>'
SET @str = @str + '     <age>42</age>'
SET @str = @str + '  </user>'
SET @str = @str + '  <user>'
SET @str = @str + '     <firstName>Sarah</firstName>'
SET @str = @str + '     <lastName>Brown</lastName>'
SET @str = @str + '     <age>23</age>'
SET @str = @str + '  </user>'
SET @str = @str + '</users>'

DECLARE @xml xml
SELECT @xml = CAST(CAST(@str AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML) 

--  Iterate through each of the "users\user" records in our XML
SELECT 
    x.Rec.query('./firstName').value('.', 'nvarchar(2000)') AS 'FirstName',
    x.Rec.query('./lastName').value('.', 'nvarchar(2000)') AS 'LastName',
    x.Rec.query('./age').value('.', 'int') AS 'Age'
FROM @xml.nodes('/users/user') as x(Rec)
```

This gives us these results:

[image]

Cool, hey ?

The downside is that this isn't particularly fast.

In my app, I use code like this, but write out the "table version" of this data into a regular SQL Server table.

You *really* don't want to be trying to do reporting based on directly loading and parsing XML blobs...